# My navbar submenu doesn't disappear when I hover out of the nav link

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

**Context**: I'm trying to create a navbar with a sub menu that appears and disappears through hovering.

```js
const about = document.querySelector('.about')
const services = document.querySelector('.services')
const abtDrpdwn = document.querySelector('ul.about-submenu')
const svcDrpdwn = document.querySelector('ul.svcs-submenu')

about.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  abtDrpdwn.style.display = 'block'
})

abtDrpdwn.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  abtDrpdwn.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(198, 206, 206);
}

.logo img {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2rem 15rem 0 15rem;
}

.nav-links ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 4em;
}

ul.about-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: azure;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.svcs-submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.about-submenu li,
ul.svcs-submenu li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ul.about-submenu li a:hover,
ul.svcs-submenu li a:hover {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/creative-68-225308.png'>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class='about'>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class='about-submenu'>
          <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='services'>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class='svcs-submenu'>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Action**: I tried using `mouseenter`/`mouseover` to make the sub-menu appear, and `mouseleave` to make it disappear.

**Result**: The sub menu appears when I hover over the nav link. The sub menu disappears when I hover out of the sub menu. However, the sub menu **doesn't disappear when you hover out of the nav link**.

**Expected Result**: The sub menu disappears when you hover out of the nav link and sub menu.

Answer (score 0):

The desired effect can be achieved with CSS alone, without Javascript. Look at the following code and combine with the more detailed formatting rules (such as `padding` and `background-color`) from your stylesheet:

```css
.nav-links>ul>li { position: relative; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
.nav-links>ul>li:not(:hover) ul { display: none; }
.about-submenu, .svcs-submenu { position: absolute; width: max-content; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class='about'>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class='about-submenu'>
          <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='services'>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class='svcs-submenu'>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But rather than using class names like `about-submenu`, that are used only once, you should give all your submenus a common class, such as

```
<ul class='about submenu'>
...
<ul class='svcs submenu'>
```

and perhaps also for the top-level menus. This would simplify the CSS even more.